# msvcr110_clr0400.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I had installed source tree on my machine and after the installation is complete and when I try to launch the source tree I am seeing this error. "msvcr110_clr0400.dll is missing from your computer" [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the .net framework 4.5